# How to fairly compare performances of different deep learning models?

Tags: deep-learning

I have seen in many papers that when comparing different deep learning models, the training hyperparameters such as batch size and learning rate are set the same for all models. Is this setting reasonable? I believe that different models may have different optimal hyperparameter values. For example, some models may achieve the best performance with a batch size of 4, while others may require a batch size of 32 to reach optimal performance.

I want to compare my new model with previous SOTA models and publish a paper, but don't know how to make a fair model performance comparison.

Comment: Hyperparameters are the least of the issues. Models can vary by wide margins in number of parameters, amount of data required to train, etc. As a consequence, not everything is apples to apples, so you compare other aspects of performance (speed of throughput, cost to run inference, etc.).

Comment: @erip Thanks for your reply. I want to compare model performances in terms of loss and accuracy. But I don't know if it is fair to train these models with same set of hyperparameters (e.g. batch size, learning rate).